# ORA-02070: database %s%s does not support %s in this context

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I have an Oracle database from which I am selecting a table from a remote postgres database, pg. The column mydate is of type date.

```
select to_char(mydate,'mm-dd-yyyy') from "pg_table"@pg
```

For the above query, I am getting an error like

> ORA-02070: database PG does not support TO_CHAR in this context
>   *Cause:    The remote database does not support the named capability in the context in which it is used.
>   *Action:   Simplify the SQL statement.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are accessing a table "pg_table" which resides in a database behind a database link. Which database is it (Oracle? Something else?). Is that table really created in lower case? What is MYDATE column's datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `to_date` to first make it an oracle date then use `to_char` to transform

```
      select to_char(to_date(mydate),'mm-dd-yyyy' ) as "Date"
     from "pg_table"@pg
```

Comment: check your pg date's exact format. try without to_char debug without using format func()

Answer (score 0):

Some functions are not supported by the linked server driver to the backend server. I'm having this happen right now where regex_replace is not supported by links to MSSQL. This is just an unfortunate byproduct of using a linked server.